# Facebook User Authentication in C#/WPF?

Tags: facebook

I am new to Facebook app development and have stumbled across a road block. After reading the documentation, I sort of understand that the process of using Facebook login is done in there steps: user authentication -> app authorization -> app authentication. I see where the app authroization/authentication is done, but I can't seem to figure out how to bring up a "user login" screen of Facebook on my WPF. Can anyone advise? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to register a application in Facebook. Don't forget to give a canvas url when registering an application. After registration you should get app id and app secret values.

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL
```

- `YOUR_APP_ID` means your application id
- `YOUR_URL` means that application canvas url.

Wpf has a web browser control, you just call the Navigate function and give this url.  You should get a Facebook login dialog.

After giving the correct user id and password, Facebook should popup a permission dialog then click the `Allow` button , you should get a code with redirect url.  Then you should parse the code from this url and create a web request to get an access token:

`https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL&     client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&code=THE_CODE_FROM_ABOVE`

- `YOUR_APP_ID` is application id
- `YOUR_URL` is application redirect url
- `YOUR_APP_SECRET` means application secret
- `THE_CODE_FROM_ABOVE` code get from above.

After executing this request, you should get an access token. Using this token you can access Facebook functionality from your application.

Comment: Note that the WebBrowser control uses an IE browser engine even older than IE, and Facebook is trying to use the "slice" API that does not work there. You need to use the WebView control for it to work now, from Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls.WebView